# nth-child stops working after some time

Tags: html, css

This is how my code looks like. I removed some parts. So, don't worry if you see some syntax error or something like that.

```
 <?php for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){ ?>
        <div id="my-ads-block">
            <div id="my-ads-name">
                <a href=""><?php echo $title[$i]; ?></a>
            </div>
            <div id="my-ads-content">
                <div id="my-ads-picture">
                    <a href="<?php echo $picture[$i] ?>">
                        <img src="/<?php echo $picture[$i] ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="my-ads-menu">
                    <div class="my-ads-buttons"><span>Posted Date: </span><?php echo date_format($date[$i],"F j, Y") ?></div>
                    <div class="my-ads-buttons"><span>Price: </span><?php setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_CA'); echo money_format('$%!i', $price[$i]); ?></div>
                    <div class="my-ads-buttons"><a href="<?php echo $book_id[$i]; ?>">Edit This Ad</a></div>
                    <div class="my-ads-buttons"><a href="<?php echo $book_id[$i]; ?>">Delete This Ad</a></div>
                    <div class="my-ads-buttons"><a href="<?php echo $book_id[$i]; ?>">Open This Ad</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

This is the css

```
#my-ads-block{
    width: 250px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    float: left;
}

#my-ads-block:nth-child(3n){
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

I print small boxes which contains some informations and one page can have 3 boxes next to each other. So, I would like to explain with some examples.

The code above, should print columns like this

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

But the problem is, it prints like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
  7
8 9 10
```

So, after 6th element, something goes wrong and I cannot figure out why. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can't reuse IDs in your DOM, you should be using classes for repeated elements

Comment: my guess is that block 4 and 6 are slightly larger than 5, which will explain why your layout will push down those blocks when using floating elements.  You can confirm this by setting an explicit height and handling the overflow (hidden, auto, visible).

Comment: tribe you were right. there was 1px difference in height. The blocks have pictures inside and one of the pictures is expanding the height 1cm. Thank you